# Single row value change is reflected in all the drawers

Tags: reactjs

I have two drawer components and inside those drawer user can select maximum 3 rows. Each row has a `Accessory Qty` property which cannot be greater than `Max Qty.`
[image: Two Drawers, each with clickHandler which triggers inner row sections] 
Two Drawers, each with clickHandler which triggers inner row sections

[image: Rows inside a drawer, user can add 1 or more rows] 
Each row has `Accessory Qty` and `Max Qty.` as mentioned above.
[image: selecting all] 
Selecting all the rows and clicking `Associate to all` which adds the selected rows in the other drawers. You can see in the breadcrumbs that currently I'm in `SET F`. Now after going back to Image one, when I click the 2nd drawer which is `SET H` I can see that the selected Items are added here.
[image: set H]
Now if I change any value in any of the rows of `SET H` the same change is reflected in the `SET F`
[image] 
[image]

**This is the whole problem, I want the changes not to reflect in other drawers**.

For this data is getting fetched from the API. I'm setting a copy of the data in the `backupdata`. Then with the index and values I'm changing the values in the corresponding rows.

**handleQtyChange**

```
  const handleQtyChange = (event, i) => {
    console.log("Set Index QTY", index, i);
    const backupdata = [...billOfMaterials];
    var data = event.target.value;
    if (backupdata[index].accessory_details[i].accessory[0].code !== "") {

      var accesory_code =
        backupdata[index].accessory_details[i].accessory[0].code;
      var max_qty = backupdata[index].accessory_details[i].max_qty;
      var updated_qty = event.target.value;

      if (parseFloat(updated_qty) > parseFloat(max_qty)) {
        setMessageDialog({
          isOpen: true,
          message: "Qty must be less than or equal to Max qty",
          severity: "error",
        });
      } else {
        if (data == "" || (!isNaN(+data) && parseFloat(data) >= 0)) {
          console.log("AccessoryChildIndex", i);
          console.log("Max qty", accessoryListWithMaxQty);
          console.log("Set Index", index);
          setMessageDialog({
            isOpen: false,
            message: "",
            severity: "error",
          });
          var accessory_total_qty_index = backupdata[
            index
          ].accessory_total_qty.findIndex(
            (x) =>
              x.code == backupdata[index].accessory_details[i].accessory[0].code
          );
          console.log("accessory_total_qty Index", accessory_total_qty_index);
          backupdata[index].accessory_total_qty[accessory_total_qty_index].qty =
            updated_qty;
          backupdata[index].accessory_details[i].accessory_qty = updated_qty;
          backupdata[index].accessory_details[i].total = (
            parseFloat(
              event.target.value == undefined || event.target.value == ""
                ? 0
                : event.target.value
            ) * parseFloat(backupdata[index].accessory_details[i].rate)
          ).toFixed(2);
          backupdata[index].grand_total = grandTotal();
          setBillOfMaterials(backupdata);
          if (!checkBomAccessoryWiseTotalQty(accesory_code, max_qty)) {
            setMessageDialog({
              isOpen: true,
              message: "Qty limit exceed max qty would be " + max_qty,
              severity: "error",
            });
            backupdata[index].accessory_total_qty[
              accessory_total_qty_index
            ].qty = 0;
            backupdata[index].accessory_details[i].accessory_qty = 0;
            backupdata[index].accessory_details[i].total = 0;
            backupdata[index].grand_total = grandTotal();
            setBillOfMaterials(backupdata);
          }
          console.log("Change BOM", billOfMaterials);
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

**handleAssociateToAll**

```
  const handleAssociateToAll = () => {
    //var data = [...billOfMaterials];
    var backupdata = [...billOfMaterials];
    //var backupdata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([...billOfMaterials]));

    var selectedData = backupdata[index].accessory_details.filter((el) => {
      return el.is_selected == true;
    });
    console.log(selectedData);
    console.log(index);
    backupdata.map((el, i) => {
      if (index != i) {
        console.log(selectedData);
        selectedData.map((dt) => {
          dt.accessory_qty = "0";
          dt.is_selected = false;
          let checkAccessory = backupdata[i].accessory_details.find((data) => {
            return (
              data.accessory[0].code != "" &&
              data.accessory[0].code == dt.accessory[0].code
            );
          });
          console.log("Check", checkAccessory);
          if (checkAccessory == undefined) {
            backupdata[i].accessory_details = [
              dt,
              ...backupdata[i].accessory_details,
            ];
          }
        });
        backupdata[index].accessory_total_qty &&
          backupdata[index].accessory_total_qty.map((qty) => {
            qty.qty = "0";
            let checkTotalQty = backupdata[i].accessory_total_qty.find(
              (data) => {
                return data.code == qty.code;
              }
            );
            if (checkTotalQty == undefined) {
              backupdata[i].accessory_total_qty = [
                ...backupdata[i].accessory_total_qty,
                qty,
              ];
            }
          });
      }
    });
    setBillOfMaterials(backupdata);
    checkAllSelected();
  };
  console.log("bill", billOfMaterials);
```

I guess I've explained well. So how do I keep the other drawer's data unchanged and change only the selected drawers rows.

**The api response**
After clicking Associate to all:
[image]

The overall bill, the selected rows are added in `accessory_total_qty`:
[image]